# PHP how I can pass arguments to constant

Tags: php

I'm looking for a solution to pass arguments to a dynamic constant Name.

```
 <?php 
 class L {
   const profile_tag_1 = 'Bla bla Age from %s to %s';
   const profile_tag_2 = 'Wow Wow Age from %s to %s';

   public static function __callStatic($string, $args) {
      return vsprintf(constant("self::" . $string), $args);
   }
 }
```

My code

```
 $x = 1;
 echo constant("L::profile_tag_".$x); // arguments: 20, 30
```

I want get

```
 Bla bla Age from 20 to 30
```

How can I pass my two arguments to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `func_get_args()` and `array_shift()` to isolate the constant string name.
[[Codepad live](http://codepad.org/gvXOzjme)]

```
<?php 
 class L {
   const profile_tag_1 = 'Bla bla Age from %s to %s';
   const profile_tag_2 = 'Wow Wow Age from %s to %s';

   public static function __callStatic() {
      $args = func_get_args();
      $string = array_shift($args);
      return vsprintf(constant('self::' . $string), $args);
   }
 }


L::__callStatic('profile_tag_1',12,12);
```

But, be aware when using this function with a generic call to a static method, you need to change `__callStatic` signature to allow `$name` and `$arguments` like this:

```
 class L {
   const profile_tag_1 = 'Bla bla Age from %s to %s';
   const profile_tag_2 = 'Wow Wow Age from %s to %s';

   public static function __callStatic($name, $args) {
      $string = array_shift($args);
      return vsprintf(constant('self::' . $string), $args);
   }
 }


L::format('profile_tag_1',12,12);
```

### A better way

Although, there is a better way to perform what you need (read Yoshi in comments), considering you are using everything static:

```
 echo sprintf(L::profile_tag_1,12,14);
```

You don't even need a `Class` at this point.

Comment: No need to use `__callStatic` even. A *good* readable name would also work. No magic needed. e.g. `L::format(L::profile_tag_1, 20, 30);` (imo)

Comment: I know, though I think it really should. Using the constant the way it's meant to be has just too many advantages (e.g. code inspection...).

Comment: @dynamic This is a yery informative answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
echo L::__callStatic("profile_tag_".$x, array(20, 30));
```